# How to prove this function surjective?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

$f:R \to C=\{c \in \mathbb{C}^* : |c|=1\}$ defined by $f(a)=e^{2 \pi i a}.$

I'm stuck with how to go about finding $a$ for every element in the set $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any complex number can be written as $$z=re^{i\theta},\ \theta\in [0,2\pi)$$ So, $f(a)=e^{i2\pi a},\  f:\mathbb{R}\to C\implies e^{i2\pi a}= e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ since $e^{i\theta}\in C$, so $2\pi a=\theta +2\pi k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This basically is what's being asked to prove.

Comment: Is it okay now or some thing more needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

I preassume that you are aware of the surjectivity of function $\cos:\mathbb R\rightarrow[-1,1]$

Any $c\in\mathbb C$  can be written as $c=a+bi$.

If moreover $|c|=1$ then we have $a^2+b^2=1$.

That means that $a\in[-1,1]$ so $a=\cos2\pi\phi$ for some $\phi$.

Then $b^2=1-\cos^22\pi\phi=\sin^22\pi\phi$ so that $b=\sin2\pi\phi$ or $b=-\sin2\pi\phi$.

In the first case we are ready: $e^{2\pi i\phi}=\cos2\pi\phi+i\sin2\pi\phi=a+bi$.

In the second case we have $a=\cos2\pi\psi$ and $b=\sin2\pi\psi$ for $\psi:=-\phi$ so that $e^{2\pi i\psi}=a+bi$.